# How to Notify other NiFi processor on some state or event change

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I am planing to have a NiFi Flow like below, but now I am stuck at notifying from one processor to other process on some state change fail->fail->fail->success->success, I need to notify and start other process only when state change from fail->success.

Here my send processor continuously trying to send to third-party server and if any fail happens(due third party server going down) it will send the flow file to other process and other process persist failed data in some data store.

After that send processor continues sending new file flow as the new file coming in, when it get success to send the new file to third party server**, this needs to notify other process so that other process can start read from failed data store and start sending failed record to third party server**, so now both failed files and new files be sending to third party server.

I am going with approach because third party server does not wants any delay in new files once he is back 
.

**is the approach works with scale like 50000 file per second, each file is around 500 bytes, so 25MBs and in future I may need to achieve 1GBps?**

**How to notify other process on some state change ?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Notify and Wait processors. Basically you can route a file to a Wait processor and tell the Wait processor about an expression that you watch for. Once a Notify processor that is connected to the Wait processor sets the signal to the expected value, the file is released.

The magic behind this happens in a DistributedMapCache controller service that is shared between the two processors; you will also have to create that one.

The core [NiFi documentation](http://nifi.apache.org/docs.html) is complete but a bit terse to get started. However, I found some good introductory articles [here](https://medium.com/@rahulsoni4u/trigger-based-serial-data-processing-in-nifi-using-wait-and-notify-processor-fa6e0359c6da) and [here](http://ijokarumawak.github.io/nifi/2017/02/02/nifi-notify-batch/). The second one also had some performance benchmark data. The author managed to get almost 8 MB/sec out of his setup, which is way more than you need; however he used bigger files.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for details .. I just curious about scaling in future , my current retirement is 25MB/sec, 1 year down the line requirement is 1GB/sec. so will NiFi horizontally scale ? if it can not scale then Can I do it by adding few more NiFi nodes with adding logic in my read processor ?